# How to make lightbox scroll the lightbox and not the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the lightbox_me jquery plugin to open a lightbox when a user clicks on a product. Often the lightbox content stretches below the fold, and at the moment the right scrollbar moves the entire page when you scroll down.

I'd like it to work like the pinterest lightbox, whereby the right scrollbar only scrolls the lightbox, and the rest of the page stays fixed. I've seen a few posts on this, but nothing seems to work for me.

```
jQuery(function(){


$('.productBoxLink').click(function(e) {
    var box = $(this).siblings(".productLightboxContent").html();
    $('.lightBox').lightbox_me({
        centered: false,
        modalCSS:  {top: '50px'},
        onLoad: function() { 
              $('.productLightbox').html(box);
              $('.productUpdateInner').show();
            },
        onClose: function() {
              $('.productUpdateInner').hide();
            }
        });
    return false;
  });
});


.lightBox {
width: 450px;
background-color: #fff;
top: 400px;
position: fixed;
padding: 30px;
text-align: center;
display: none;
clear: both;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5C5C5C;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5C5C5C;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5C5C5C;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I've read that this can be done with a few changes to my CSS. Does anyone know how I can achieve this with the code shown? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to .lightBox:

```
height:600px; /* You need to set a specific height - px or %*/
overflow-x:scroll; /* Tell the container to scroll if the content goes beyond bounds*/
```

**Update**

```
width:100%;
overflow-x:scroll;
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response Lowkase! Do you know how I can get the scrollbar to replace the main right scrollbar as opposed to appearing within the lightbox? Perhaps I need to assign the overflow property to the lightbox background instead.

Comment: Do you want the scrollbar to appear for the main lightbox container... OR.. do you want a scroll bar for the page (e.g. - body tag)?  Having a hard time understanding where you need the scrollbar to appear.  If you can post an image of what you want to help us understand.

Comment: I think I want the latter of what you mentioned. See here, if you click the top left item so the lightbox appears, the far right scrollbar scrolls the lightbox and the page stays fixed. http://pinterest.com/asos/asos-3-s-s-s13-the-f-word/

Comment: Ahh, what your seeing is an optical illusion.  The lightbox is set to take up width:100%  (essentially the entire viewport).  So use my code above and set the width to 100% and the overflow and you should have a similar effect.  The amount of content in the lightbox will determine if it scrolls or not.  You can set height:100% to ensure the lightbox takes up the full viewport height.

Comment: Oh I see, I'd never thought of doing it that way. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let it size larger than the viewport, it's most likely because of your `position: fixed` line. Change it to `position: absolute` and you should be good.

Both fixed and absolute take the element out of the document flow, so there should be no net change in how it presents, but `fixed` fixes it to that specific position and forces it to not move ever.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a general answer would be to make the background of the lighbox (i.e. the content before lightbox; the main content wrapper) `position: fixed;` and adjust its **top** value with javascript to a negative value corresponding to the position of user scroll in the moment of lightbox opening. Besides that, the lightbox would need to be `position: absolute;` with the same **top** / **left** values as if it was fixed.

When the user closes the lightbox, the previous values would need to be restored.

Answer (score 0):

Add to html a class when lightbox is opening. For example:

```
.lightbox-active{overflow:hidden}
```

Also, your lightbox should have the next style:

```
.lightbox{overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll}
```

When you close the lightbox, you have remove the lightbox-active class from html.