# Description below the image goes off screen on popup of lightbox.js

Tags: lightbox

I am using lightbox.js for image pop-up. Everything works perfect.

**But when I add description (i.e data-title) then its content goes off
   screen.**

Can anyone please suggest me any workaround so that I can have both
   image and description on the screen.

(For small description everything works fine. But if description is
   large then only I am facing this issue)

Please refer the below screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Can you recreate this in JSFiddle?

Comment: I found the work-around here for scroll if image/description goes off screen --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274445/how-to-make-lightbox-scroll-the-lightbox-and-not-the-page#comment21548739_15274511